# After install using easy_install, still get import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, easy-install

So I'm trying to install pyshp and pyproj for an assignment in a class, and I'm trying to use easy_install.  I've used it before and it worked, but this time, with both of these packages, I pull up the Command Prompt (Admin) and run:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install pyshp
Searching for pyshp
Best match: pyshp 1.2.1
Processing pyshp-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
pyshp 1.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\users\adam\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyshp-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyshp
Finished processing dependencies for pyshp
```

So great, looks to me like it worked.  Then I run

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
...
>>>import pyshp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyshp
```

I've looked for similar problems in other people's questions but I don't see this come up exactly, or I don't see a solution offered.  I saw one thing say that if you enter the command

```
>easy_install .
```

it'll set up or do something to packages that have already been downloaded and installed, but I tried that and it didn't change anything.

All the same basic stuff happens when I do this with pyproj too.  Any idea what's going on?

[Edit:  Also, I just searched my computer for anything with "pyproj" in the name and there's nothing.  So it sounds like nothing got downloaded or installed at all.  I'm confused.]

Comment: You should use `pip` instead of `easy_install`

Comment: @Falmarri Can you say why?  I actually did try using pip and I am still having the same problem--but is pip better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the name of the package is `pyshp`, the library is called `shapefile` as you can read in the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp). So your import should be:

```
import shapefile
```

Comment: Holy hell that was simple... Thanks!